# Communication with Allah

Tags: salat, allah, dua

Assalamoalaikum
Recently I have been praying for something to be happen, its been 1.5months that I am making dua for it even offering salat-e-hajat also repenting to Allah. Due to some facts it is kind of obvious that the thing I want will not happen. But one day in jummah prayer I heard that my heart was saying that dont worry this will happen soon. I want to ask was it my own mind or Allah was guiding me through my heart?

Answer (score 0):

Allah is saying that it’s gonna come don’t worry keep doing dua and in,sha,allah it will get accepted it should be good not bad duas if it’s good then just keep asking keep asking I asked for duas and it got accepted alhamdulal trust me patience is everything have patience